# How do I shift categorical scatter markers to left and right above xticks (multiple data sets per category)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a simple pandas dataframe that I want to plot with matplotlib:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('SAT_data.xlsx', index_col = 'State')

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df['Year'], df['Reading'], c = 'blue', s = 25)
plt.scatter(df['Year'], df['Math'], c = 'orange', s = 25)
plt.scatter(df['Year'], df['Writing'], c = 'red', s = 25)
```

Here is what my plot looks like:

[image: Plot of my Data]

I'd like to shift the blue data points a bit to the left, and the red ones a bit to the right, so each year on the x-axis has three mini-columns of scatter data above it instead of all three datasets overlapping.  I tried and failed to use the 'verts' argument properly.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

Using an offset transform would allow to shift the scatter points by some amount in units of points instead of data units. The advantage is that they would then always sit tight against each other, independent of the figure size, zoom level etc.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

year = np.random.choice(np.arange(2006,2017), size=(300) ) 
values = np.random.rand(300, 3)

plt.figure()

offset = lambda p: transforms.ScaledTranslation(p/72.,0, plt.gcf().dpi_scale_trans)
trans = plt.gca().transData

sc1 = plt.scatter(year, values[:,0], c = 'blue', s = 25, transform=trans+offset(-5))
plt.scatter(year, values[:,1], c = 'orange', s = 25)
plt.scatter(year, values[:,2], c = 'red', s = 25, transform=trans+offset(5))

plt.show()
```

**Broad figure:**
[image]
**Normal figure:**
[image]
**Zoom**
[image]

Some explanation:

The problem is that we want to add an offset in points to some data in data coordinates. While data coordinates are automatically transformed to display coordinates using the `transData` (which we normally don't even see on the surface), adding some offset requires us to change the transform.
We do this by adding an offset.  While we could just add an offset in pixels (display coordinates), it is more convenient to add the offset in points and thereby using the same unit as the size of the scatter points is given in (their size is points squared actually). 
So we want to know how many pixels are `p` points? This is found out by dividing `p` by the ppi (points per inch) to obtain inches, and then by multiplying by the dpi (dots per inch) to obtain the display pixel. This calculation in done in the ScaledTranslation.
While the dots per inch are in principle variable (and taken care of by the `dpi_scale_trans` transform), the points per inch are fixed. Matplotlib uses 72 ppi, which is kind of a [typesetting standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_%28typography%29).

Comment: There's some serious black magic going on here =). Would you mind explaining where the number 72 in the offset transform comes from?

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way would be to create a small offset `dx` and subtract it from `x` values of blue points and add to `x` values of red points.

```
dx = 0.1
plt.scatter(df['Year'] - dx, df['Reading'], c = 'blue', s = 25) 
plt.scatter(df['Year'],      df['Math'], c = 'orange', s = 25) 
plt.scatter(df['Year'] + dx, df['Writing'], c = 'red', s = 25)
```

One more option could be to use [stripplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) function from `seaborn` library. It would be necessary to melt the original dataframe into long form so that each row contains a year, a test and a score. Then make a `stripplot` specifying year as `x`, score as `y` and test as `hue`. The `split` keyword argument is what controls plotting categories as separate stripes for each `x`. There's also the `jitter` argument that will add some noise to `x` values so that they take up some small area instead of being on a single vertical line.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# make up example data
np.random.seed(2017)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Reading','Math','Writing'], 
                  data = np.random.normal(540,30,size=(1000,3)))
df['Year'] = np.random.choice(np.arange(2006,2016),size=1000)

# melt the data into long form
df1 = pd.melt(df, var_name='Test', value_name='Score',id_vars=['Year'])

# make a stripplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
sns.stripplot(data = df1, x='Year', y = 'Score', hue = 'Test', 
              jitter = True, split = True, alpha = 0.7, 
              palette = ['blue','orange','red'])
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how the given code can be adapted to work with multiple subplots, and also to a situation without "middle column".

To adapt the given code, `ax[n,p].transData` is needed instead of `plt.gca().transData`. `plt.gca()` refers to the last created subplot, while now you'll need the transform of each individual subplot.

Another problem is that when only plotting via a transform, matplotlib doesn't automatically sets the lower and upper limits of the subplot. In the given example plots the points "in the middle" without setting a specific transform, and the plot gets "zoomed out" around these points (orange in the example).

If you don't have points at the center, the limits need to be set in another way.  The way I came up with, is plotting some dummy points in the middle (which sets the zooming limits), and remove those again.

Also note that the size of the scatter dots in given as the square of their diameter (measured in "unit points"). To have touching dots, you'd need to use the square root for their offset.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms
import numpy as np

# Set up data for reproducible example
year = np.random.choice(np.arange(2006, 2017), size=(100))
data = np.random.rand(4, 100, 3)
data2 = np.random.rand(4, 100, 3)

# Create plot and set up subplot ax loop
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(18, 14))

# Set up offset with transform
offset = lambda p: transforms.ScaledTranslation(p / 72., 0, plt.gcf().dpi_scale_trans)

# Plot data in a loop
for ax, q, r in zip(axs.flat, data, data2):
    temp_points = ax.plot(year, q, ls=' ')
    for pnt in temp_points:
        pnt.remove()
    ax.plot(year, q, marker='.', ls=' ', ms=10, c='b', transform=ax.transData + offset(-np.sqrt(10)))
    ax.plot(year, r, marker='.', ls=' ', ms=10, c='g', transform=ax.transData + offset(+np.sqrt(10)))

plt.show()
```

[image: touching scatter points]