# How do I shift categorical data point markers to the left and right above xticks for subplots?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, transform

I was able to offset markers in a single plot following: [How do I shift categorical scatter markers to left and right above xticks (multiple data sets per category)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126064/how-do-i-shift-categorical-scatter-markers-to-left-and-right-above-xticks-multi)

This method sets up the transform

```
offset = lambda p: transforms.ScaledTranslation(p/72.,0, plt.gcf().dpi_scale_trans)
trans = plt.gca().transData
```

And applies it the plot

```
sc1 = plt.scatter(year, values[:,0], c = 'blue', s = 25, transform=trans+offset(-5))
```

But when I try the same method using subplots, I end up with a lot of blank plots or markers scattered randomly. Below is a reproducible example of what the graphs generally look like

```
#Libraries needed
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms

#Set up data for reproducible example
year = np.random.choice(np.arange(2006,2017), size=(100) ) 
values1 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
values2 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
values3 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
values4 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
values5 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
values6 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
values7 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
values8 = np.random.rand(100, 3)
data = [values1, values2, values3, values4]
data2= [values5, values6, values7, values8]

#Create plot and set up subplot ax loop
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize = (18,14))
axx = 0, 0, 1, 1
axy = 0, 1, 0, 1

#Set up offset with transform
offset = lambda p: transforms.ScaledTranslation(p/72.,0, plt.gcf().dpi_scale_trans)
trans = plt.gca().transData

#Plot data in a loop
for n, p, q, r in zip(axx, axy, data, data2):
    ax[n,p].plot(year, q, marker='.', ls=' ', ms=10, c = 'b')
    ax[n,p].plot(year, r, marker='.', ls=' ', ms=10, c = 'g')
    
plt.show()
```

Now when I add the transform parameter, the output becomes blank

```
#Plot data in a loop
for n, p, q, r in zip(axx, axy, data, data2):
    ax[n,p].plot(year, q, marker='.', ls=' ', ms=10, c = 'b', transform=trans+offset(-5))
    ax[n,p].plot(year, r, marker='.', ls=' ', ms=10, c = 'g', transform=trans+offset(5))
    
plt.show()
```

I've spent a lot of time digging into different aspects of the transform parameter but am having trouble finding a solution. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Instead of `plt.gca().transData` you'd need `ax[n,p].transData`. So `ax[n,p].plot(year, q, ..., transform=ax[n,p].transData+offset(-5))`. `plt.gca()` refers to the last created subplot.

Comment: @JohanC That results in an output of only the axes. No data plots.

Comment: I added a new answer to the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74405222/12046409) to deal with multiple subplots, and without dots in the middle.